# How to run the python file in remote machine directory?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

**Details:**

- I am having xxx.py file in B machine.
- I trying to execute that xxx.python file from A machine by using python script.

Comment: what os are you using?

Answer (score 3):

assuming you have ssh access you can use [paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/)

here's an example that checks diskspace on a remote host:

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.load_host_keys('/path/to/known_hosts')
#ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
my_key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file('/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa')
ssh.connect(HOST, username="whatever", pkey=my_key)
i, o, e = ssh.exec_command('df -h /')
print int(o.readlines()[1].split()[3].replace('G', ''))
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have done something to specifically allow this, such as SSH into machine B first, you cannot do this.

That's a basic safety consideration. If any host A could execute any script on host B, it would be extremely easy to run malicious code on other machines.